# Kuberenets Web UI (Dashboard) missing graphs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

I have installed Docker v1.13 and Kubernetes with Kubeadm v1.6. Then I installed Web UI (Dashboard). I can access it but its missing CPU/Memory usage graphs... Why could this happen?

Comment: Did you install [heapster](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster) as an addon? I think this is necessary in order to see the graphs - at least in k8s 1.4

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the usage graphs worked once I installed [heapster](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster) as an addon. Heapster requires an influxdb as data sink for the metric storage. Luckily you can deploy all those easily in k8s with the following definitions in the `kube-system` namespace (tested it with k8s [1.4.6](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.4.6)):

**heapster-service.yml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    task: monitoring
    # For use as a Cluster add-on (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons)
    # If you are NOT using this as an addon, you should comment out this line.
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: 'true'
    kubernetes.io/name: Heapster
  name: heapster
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8082
  selector:
    k8s-app: heapster
```

**heapster-deployment.yml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: heapster
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        task: monitoring
        k8s-app: heapster
        version: v6
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: heapster
        image: kubernetes/heapster:canary
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command:
        - /heapster
        - --source=kubernetes:https://kubernetes.default
        - --sink=influxdb:http://monitoring-influxdb:8086
```

**influxdb-service.yml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    task: monitoring
    # For use as a Cluster add-on (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons)
    # If you are NOT using this as an addon, you should comment out this line.
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: 'true'
    kubernetes.io/name: monitoring-influxdb
  name: monitoring-influxdb
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  # type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: api 
    port: 8086
    targetPort: 8086
  selector:
    k8s-app: influxdb
```

**infuxdb-deployment.yml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: monitoring-influxdb
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        task: monitoring
        k8s-app: influxdb
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: influxdb-storage
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: influxdb
        image: kubernetes/heapster_influxdb:v0.6
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "256M"
            cpu: "0.1"
          limits:
            memory: "1G"
            cpu: "1.0"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: influxdb-storage
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution!