# Kubernetes Web UI (Dashboard) doesn't show graphs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dashboard

I have installed Docker v17.06-ce on 2 minion nodes plus a master node and Kubernetes with Kubeadm v1.7.0. Then I deployed Web UI (Dashboard) with `kubectl create -f https://git.io/kube-dashboard` and changed type to *NodePort* using `kubectl edit service kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system`.

I can access it but its missing CPU/Memory usage graphs. So I've followed the instructions from [Kuberenets Web UI (Dashboard) missing graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832273/kuberenets-web-ui-dashboard-missing-graphs) to deploy heapster and influxdb, but I still can't see the graps...

What's going wrong?

UPDATE:
checking logs `kubectl logs heapster-2994581613-m28hh --namespace=kube-system` I've found these errors repeatedly:

```
E0717 09:14:05.000881       7 kubelet.go:271] No nodes received from APIserver.
E0717 09:14:05.947260       7 reflector.go:203] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/processors/node_autoscaling_enricher.go:100: Failed to list *api.Node: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get nodes)
E0717 09:14:05.959150       7 reflector.go:203] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/heapster.go:319: Failed to list *api.Pod: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get pods)
E0717 09:14:05.959254       7 reflector.go:203] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/heapster.go:327: Failed to list *api.Node: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get nodes)
E0717 09:14:05.959888       7 reflector.go:203] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/sources/kubelet/kubelet.go:342: Failed to list *api.Node: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get nodes)
E0717 09:14:05.959995       7 reflector.go:203] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/processors/namespace_based_enricher.go:84: Failed to list *api.Namespace: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get namespaces)
E0717 09:14:06.957399       7 reflector.go:203] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/processors/node_autoscaling_enricher.go:100: Failed to list *api.Node: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get nodes)
E0717 09:14:06.965155       7 reflector.go:203] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/sources/kubelet/kubelet.go:342: Failed to list *api.Node: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get nodes)
E0717 09:14:06.965166       7 reflector.go:203] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/heapster.go:327: Failed to list *api.Node: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get nodes)
E0717 09:14:06.966403       7 reflector.go:203] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/heapster.go:319: Failed to list *api.Pod: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get pods)
E0717 09:14:06.966964       7 reflector.go:203] k8s.io/heapster/metrics/processors/namespace_based_enricher.go:84: Failed to list *api.Namespace: the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get namespaces)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to install the heapster pod. try installing this and check.

Install the heapster rbac also.

```
kubectl  create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/heapster/master/deploy/kube-config/rbac/heapster-rbac.yaml

kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/heapster/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb/heapster.yaml
```

Comment: or you can use helm also to install the heapster.

Comment: I've tried it but the graphs are still missing. As I guess, I need also an influxdb service. Which is that I said I'd done following with this link info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832273/kuberenets-web-ui-dashboard-missing-graphs without success... Any idea?

Comment: you log message says access is missing, try to create the heapster rbac also, added comment in the post.

Comment: Yes! that's great! It works like a charm. Thanks a lot @sfgroups! I don't undestand why is this neccessary because I follow the instructions in https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/influxdb.md and there isn't anything about add a heapster rbac. Thus, you are absolutely right.